# geom_bar plot with position="dodge" and geom_text duplicating values

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

I looked on SO and I saw a lot of posts about the position of `geom_text` values related to bars but I didnt see anything related to my question. Sorry if I missed it. I am trying to create a bar plot in ggpot2 with `position="dodge"` and I am trying to put a summary value above each grouping of bars. I'm close but when I add the `geom_text` label it shows a bunch of values. Ideally I'm looking to just remove all the values but one per grouping. My reproducible example is below.  Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

```
gather.iris <- iris %>% 
gather(key=flower_att, value=measurement, -Species) %>% 
  mutate(sum_value=ifelse(Species=="setosa", 5, ifelse(Species=="versicolor", 7, 9)))

ggplot(data=gather.iris, aes(x=Species, y=measurement, fill=flower_att)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label=sum_value), vjust=-0.5, check_overlap=T)
```

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Digah.png)

Comment: What y value do you want the labels to be at? In `aes()`, you specified `y = measurement`, so you are getting a unique label for every unique combination of `measurement` on the y and `Species` on the x. If you don't want that, specify a different `y` value for the `geom_text` layer. And by "one per grouping", do you want one per x-value (Species), or one per bar (Species:measurement)?

Comment: Take a closer look at `gather.iris`. It's got 600 rows. By plotting this way, you're placing bars on top of each other over & over. Set `color = "black"` in `geom_bar` to see them split up so you see what I mean. For each of these, you're then plotting an item of text. Do you want to be plotting a summary value instead?

Comment: To see @camille's point, add `alpha=.2` to the `geom_bar()`. You're doing a lot of weird over-plotting here.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was just trying to make something I could share quickly because I can not share my data. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Gregor for the quick answer. I didn't understand that I needed to chose a x and y value for the text like I would a plot. Heres a not so pretty answer to the question.

```
gather.iris <- iris %>% gather(key=flower_att, value=measurement, -Species) %>% 
  mutate(sum_value=ifelse(Species=="setosa", 5, ifelse(Species=="versicolor", 7, 9)))

ggplot(data=gather.iris, aes(x=Species, y=measurement, fill=flower_att)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(y=as.numeric(Species), label=sum_value), vjust=-0.5, check_overlap=T)
```

[image]